# How to get 1 third slabs using commands

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get 1 third slabs command in minecraft. The slabs:

1. Can be placed on each other no matter what.
2. If it's a chest, or an interacting block, can be used
3. `/block` commands apparently don't work

Comment: What the… How did you get the idea that ⅓ slabs exist? What is `/block` supposed to mean or do? And I have no idea what #1 and #2 are supposed to mean at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that legally.

There is no such thing as a third of a block in Minecraft as it would require the block to have a number of layers/pixels/units divisible by 3. However, the blocks have a width/height of a power of 2 (8, 16, ...) and those will never be divisible by 3, since both are prime numbers. Or in short: 2^n/3 will never result in an Integer, which would be required in order to create a third of a block.

Comment: Isn't there still a way to fake a block using falling sand and shulkerboxes?  You might be able to fake a third of a block instead of the old half a block, would need to test it as I used to have issues with the falling sand snapping to the ground

Comment: @phflack if you get the falling sand to work properly you can probably get close to it, but an exact third is still not possible due to the math mentioned above. You just can't a divide a block by 3 without rounding issues.

Comment: I agree, but float/double precision is pretty close, not sure which MC uses for positions but it's close enough for most purposes